# NativeScript-Vue - Navigation from outside component

Tags: nativescript-vue

My application is receiving push notifications, when a push notification arrives, I would like to navigate to a specific component of the application.
The problem is that the callback in which I'm handling the push notification is not a vue component and so I can't
call this.$navigate.

So I tryed to inject directly Vue:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
```

and then:

```
Vue.$navigateTo(Instrument);
```

But nothing happens. (The method is correctly called).
I have no other idea to addressing this problem. Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have used:

```
Vue.navigateTo(..) or Vue.prototype.$navigateTo(..)
```